# How long would it take for all smartphones on the planet to fully reverse a SHA-256 hash?

Tags: sha256

I am aware that, theoretically speaking, there is no way to guarantee that a reversed hash is actually what is inputted to the hashing function. However, let's say that I have an image, I write down the file size of that image and then run it through the SHA-256 hashing algorithm. I then distribute the hash to all of the ~6.5 billion smartphones on our planet, along with the initial file size. How long would it take for all smartphones in existence on earth to fully brute force a SHA-256 hash, unlike Bitcoin where you only have to reverse some of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- An Apple M1 CPU can do around 2 GB/s of SHA256 (based on the optimized 2-way hardware-accelerated ARMv8 code in Bitcoin Core added in [PR24115](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/24115)) on a single core.
- Smartphones are significantly slower than M1 laptop CPUs due to power usage limitations, but let's ignore that, and conservatively overestimate every smartphone has a hexacore CPU that can do this much, so 12 GB/s per device in total.
- SHA256 operates on blocks of 64 bytes. Let's assume that the attacker picks a fixed prefix, and then just needs to grind the last 64 bytes + padding (one extra block) of the file. So they're just hashing 128 bytes. (12 GB/s) / 128 B ≈ 94 million tries per second, per device.
- 6.5 billion devices times that means 6×10<sup>17</sup> files per second in total.
- Every file attempt has a probability of 2<sup>-256</sup> of yielding a correct preimage. That means one needs in the order of 2<sup>256</sup> tries to have a reasonable chance of finding a preimage.
- 2<sup>256</sup> / 6×10<sup>17</sup> ≈ 2<sup>197</sup> seconds
- The age of the universe is around 13.7 billion years, or 2<sup>58.5</sup> seconds.
- Thus the attack would take around 2<sup>197</sup> / 2<sup>58.5</sup> ≈ 400000000000000000000000000000000000000000 times the age of the universe.